# I cannot assign a value to an array of global variables

Tags: visual-c++

I use this code in other projects is no problem, but in some cases it does not work, where is the problem.

```
TCHAR LAB[255] 
fun()
{
case IDM_LAB:
            {               
                for (int i = 0; i < 255; i++)
                {
                    LAB[i] = i;                 
                }
                MessageBox(hWnd,LAB , L"df", MB_OK);
            }
break;
}
result： 
lab==null;
```

Comment: In your `for` loop, you are assigning **zero** to the first element of the `LAB` array - and this will be the "nul terminator" signal, so it will be treated as an empty (zero-length) string when passed to functions like `MessageBox`.

Comment: @ Adrian Mole Thanks for swift response。I changed i to 50 and the result is still unassignable

Comment: I guess we'll need more code/details, then. (The code, as you've given it, won't even compile.)

Comment: @Adrian Mole Thanks, I have solved this problem,tha I wrote the wrong code. I want to fill the global array in the dialog. but I got were null pointers, so I did this experiment. Although the experiment was successful, the dialog procedure still cannot assign a value to the global array